# Ordering a set of items with constraints

Tags: algorithm

I'm looking for an algorithm that allows me to order a set so that a set of conditions are met. The conditions can only be "must appear before" or "must appear after". For example:

- A: must appear before B
- B
- C: must appear after A, must appear before D
- D: must appear before B
- E

Two valid solutions would be "ACDBE" and "EACDB". I only care to find a single valid solution.

I have no idea how to implement this. Maybe I just don't know the correct name for this, and I would be able to find information if I did.

What would be an algorithm that allows me to find a solution? Or what is this kind of algorithm called (what should I Google)?

Comment: This probably depends on what this relation provides? What kind of relation is it? Does transitivity hold for example? [Somewhat related: Total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order).

Comment: At first blush, create a directed graph from your conditions and run [Kosaraju's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosaraju%27s_algorithm). If it's a DAG, there exists one of these orderings. If not, there's some cyclic dependency and there isn't an ordering.

Comment: @sascha It's not transitive, the only thing that holds are the relationships mentioned explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).

The idea is that you can encode your dependencies in a directed graph: your set elements are nodes, and your conditions are edges. There is an edge between A and B if and only if "A must appear before B".

A topological sort is guaranteed to find a valid solution for your problem if it exists, and there are well-known algorithms with a linear time complexity on the size of the graph.

Comment: Thanks! Nice to be able to put a name to it!

Answer (score 0):

Topological sort by using graph is probably the best way to do it, yet you can follow another approach by using position based list(like  PositionalList ADT in Java) and sorting it while traversing by using "after,before" method.